# Regression using spatio-temporal data

Tags: r, software-recommendations, regression, spatio-temporal-data

I'm trying to implement a regression using R, but the various models I have tried so far do not predict well at all.

The dataset I'm working with consists of roughly 10,000 observations which correspond to 10,000 real estate transactions that all happened between 2015 and 2020. Also, all these transactions (i.e appartment sales) are located nearby (5km radius). The relevant variables I have are the following:

- price per square meter (which is the variable I'm trying to predict)
- date of transaction (dd/mm/yyyy)
- Surface of the apartment
- latitude
- longitude
- number of mains rooms

It might not be a lot to work with, but I'm still hoping to find a better model than the ones that I have implemented. I'm aware there is a model called STAR (spatio-temporal autoregressive model) that might work, however I don't know how to implement it. Indeed, I found a lot of documentation about multiple spatial models and ways to implement them in R, but they do not account for the temporal aspect of data. The STAR model supposedly works for the data I'm dealing with, but I couldn't find much about it besides research papers (many of them you can't get full access to without paying for them. However, here's a paper where it's actually explained (see page 3):

https://hal-essec.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00554695/document

There might be other ways as well, but here is what I have done so far:

To deal with the spatial aspect of the data (after the Moran test on OLS residuals confirmed spatial autocorrelation), I created a weight matrix W whose coefficients $w_i,j are such that:

w_i,j = exp(-d(i,j))     if d(i,j)<0.5 else 0, d(i,j) being the distance in km between observation i and j based on haversine formula.

The Lagrange Multiplier test then oriented me towards a SEM (spatial error model), so that's what I implemented, using the variables listed above, with the date either as a qualitative variable (using for instance the 12 semesters as modalities) or as a quantitative variable by scaling the dates (i.e converting them as numeric so number of days, and then setting the first date to 0 and last to 1)

Anyway for both regressions the MAPE (Mean Absolute Prediction Error) I obtain is around 15% (doing a 80%-20% split in train/test datasets) , so way to high.

I might not have ideal predictors or high quality data, so I might never get very good MAPE in the end. However I am convinced my weight matrix and/or the model itself could be improved, so that it captures better both the spatial and temporal autocorrelations.

Does anyone know ways or R packages/codes that would help me achieve that?

Comment: Does "However I am convinced my weight matrix and/or the model itself so that it captures better both the spatial and temporal autocorrelations." make sense? It seems there's a word missing or something, and it seems to be a crucial part of your argument about not ever getting "good" MAPE, which might not be achievable.

Comment: "I'm aware there is a model called STAR" - where did you get this awareness from? Can you point us to it? The phrase "spatio-temporal autoregressive" is a pretty generic term and you could build lots of models that were well described by that, its not just something you can plug your data into, turn a handle, and get good predictions out.

Comment: Sounds like you are interested in prediction (returning an outcome value for a given new set of input values) and not inference (describing how the outcome value relates to the input values) so that gives you all the machine learning methods beyond regression.

Comment: Yes I'm more interested in prediction than inference. But it's the first time I'm working on spatio-temporal data and I wouldn't know how to use other machine learning algorithms on such data either.